# Find upper bound from average value

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, average, trigonometric-integrals

I have been give a function, its average value, and the lower bound of an interval, I am trying to find the upper bound but I am a bit lost on how to do that. Here is what I have so far:

$$ f(x)= \frac{(e^x)}{1+e^{2x}},\quad f_{ave}=\frac{\pi}{12}(\frac{1}{\ln(\sqrt(3))}), \quad x:[0,b] $$
$$\int_1^{u(b)}\frac{du}{1+u^2}$$ $$ =\arctan(u) $$ $$= \arctan(e^x)\vert_0^b $$ $$= \arctan(e^b)-\frac{\pi}{4} $$
$$\frac{\pi}{12}(\frac{1}{\ln(\sqrt(3))}) = (\arctan(e^b)-\frac{\pi}{4}) (\frac{1}{b-0}) $$
This is about as far as I can get. Help would be monstrously appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure I parsed your question correctly: you are looking for the value(s) of $b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+xe^2}$ (or maybe $\frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}$) has average value equal to $\frac{\pi}{6\log 3}$ on the interval $(0,b)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ah, I have a formatting error in the f(x) statement. I'll fix that, thanks for pointing it out. I am looking for the b value correct.

Answer (score 1):

So we want that:
$$\int_{0}^{b}\frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}\,dx = \int_{1}^{e^b}\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\arctan(e^b)-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi b}{6\log 3}  $$
and there is exactly one positive real solution, since $f(b)=\frac{\pi b}{6\log 3}$ is a convex function that equals $0$ at $b=0$ while $g(b)=\arctan(e^b)-\frac{\pi}{4}$ is a concave function that equals $0$ at $b=0$.

An "educated guess" is to try some value of $b$ that is a rational multiple of $\log 3$, hoping to have a simple closed form for both $f(b)$ and $g(b)$.

$$ b = \frac{1}{2}\log 3 =\color{red}{\log\sqrt{3}}$$
works pretty good, since $\arctan\sqrt{3}=\frac{\pi}{3}$.